# MFC VSListBox change icons

Tags: c++, mfc

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the icons on the MFC VSListBox Dialog Control?

Specifically I'm trying to change the folder icon to a '+' icon instead:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but [`CVSListBoxBase::AddButton()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc701719) seems to be what you need.

`CVSListBox` derives from `CVSListBoxBase`, and when you call `CVSListBoxBase::SetStandardButtons` to set the buttons, it calls `AddButton()` for each button.

The documentation for `CVSListBoxBase` is unfinished, so you'll have to "play" with it, but you can read the code in afxvslistbox.cpp/.h

Comment: thanks a lot, you put me in the right direction, i'll play around with it...maybe i need to derive a class from cvslistbox.